# ObjectInputStream is not available

Tags: java

```
public class MakeNewFile{
    static HashMap<String, User> hm = new HashMap<String, User>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
        try{
            File inputFile = new File("C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\\webapps\\products\\Details.txt");  
            System.out.println("Done");
            boolean resut = inputFile.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(resut);
            System.out.println("File found");           
            //fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);                                 
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            //out.println("hiii2");
            hm= (HashMap)objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println("hiii" +hm);

            if(hm.containsKey("username"))
                { String error_msg = "Username already exist as " + "usertype";}
            else{
                User user = new User("firstname", "lastname", "email", "username","password","usertype");
                hm.put("username", user);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\\webapps\\products\\Details.txt");
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(hm);
                objectOutputStream.flush();
                objectOutputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }

    }
}
```

The file is not creating while running the code. Code is not executing of `try` block after `FileInputStream`. Where is the problem?
I tried one solution. File has been created but objectInputStream is not available.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions. Add `ex.printStackTrace();` in your catch. Add what you see as result.

Comment: Yeah, never catch an exception without doing anything with it. It will just cause confusion. If you don't feel like catching at all just declare your main method to throw an exception and let the program crash. It is much better than having a ninja-exception that you aren't noticing.

Comment: File not found, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

After running the code locally, the exception thrown is an EOF exception - java.io.EOFException. A solution would be to do a check to see if the fileInputStream is available:

```
if (fileInputStream.available() > 0) {
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);

                //out.println("hiii2");

                    hm = (HashMap) objectInputStream.readObject();

            }
```

Comment: fileInputStream is available but objectInputStream is not available. So inner if loop is not executing. What I should do now?

Comment: Changes made to the solution by removing the objectInputStream.available() check.

Comment: .this solution did not work. Still getting the same issue and not getting the output which I need

Comment: Have you noted that the solution has been edited? Delete the existing file on the drive - "Details.txt" and re-run the code.